# Folder Favorites

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for an extension or feature in VSCode that will bookmark folders for me.  I have a number of folders I continually work on and would like to open them up quickly.  The option of opening folders them in another instance of VSCode would be optimal.

Comment: 5 years later, did you find this? I'm looking for the same 

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> which presents a list of recent folders and files.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the folder or file will open a new Vscode instance.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you could install [favorites](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=howardzuo.vscode-favorites) library on your ***vscode*** as shown in it's site for add folder/file to the favorites

**Second**, it's easiest way to search a file by `ctrl+p`

Comment: this extensions does not look like it works across folders.
the idea is mark `/foo/bar/project1`, `/foo/project2`, `/another/project2` all as favorites, then have a window to select one when you open VS code empty.

Answer (score 0):

The [Favorites Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oleg-shilo.favorites) extension might help. It allows you to bookmark folders and open them in a new window (using right-click).

Answer (score -1):

It is simple. Add all folders you want to work with to one workspace :)